# What could cause Chrome to crash when getting an ajax callback?

Tags: jquery, ajax, google-chrome, bind, ecmascript-5

I have the following lines in my javascript (technically typescript) code:

```
debug.print("send ajax call : "+file);
jQuery.get('img/' + file + '.txt', this.ProcessFileData.bind(this)); // 'bind' should force the callback to remember its object - part of ECMAScript 5
debug.print("ajax call sent : " + file);
```

(The debug function is my own, it just writes to a textbox in the window, but it allows me to see that Chrome isn't crashing so far.)  But a debug line at the beginning of ProcessFileData() never gets reached in Chrome (Version 27.0.1453.110), even though it works fine in IE, Firefox and Safari.  Chrome doesn't come up with an error window, but the tab becomes unresponsive - I can't bring up developer tools, or select the text on the page etc. (though I can switch to other tabs).  What's more, a previous version of the code with some differences in the ProcessFileData function, but obviously after where the debug message would have been, works OK in Chrome too.

Replacing the middle line with either of the following:

```
jQuery.get('img/' + file + '.txt', this.ProcessFileData);
jQuery.get('img/' + file + '.txt', function () { debug.print("check"); });
```

stops Chrome from crashing (although it means the rest of the program stops working as intended), so it seems that it must be the 'bind' method causing a problem - even though that has been part of my project for 6 months (I couldn't get the callbacks to work correctly without it) and this issue only cropped up a few weeks ago.
I'm using the ddr-ecma5 library for compatibility with older browsers, but I've tried taking that out with no effect.

Does anybody know how the bind method in a callback causes a crash, and how I might get around this? Is there any way I can avoid using the bind method (which solves the problem) and still let the ProcessFileData function know which file is being returned?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have absolutely no idea why your call should fail -- it sounds like you have an infinite loop somewhere in your code.

To avoid using `bind`, save the outer `this` in some other variable and invoke `ProcessFileData` in an anonymous function:

```
var that = this;
jQuery.get('img/' + file + '.txt', function(e) {
    that.ProcessFileData(e);
});
```

Comment: I think saving the 'this' in an outer variable is what I tried before discovering the 'bind' command, but I must have been doing it wrong because I couldn't get it to work at the time.

Comment: The problem went away without any changes to my code, and the only thing I'd done was make sure the browser cache had the latest copies of all the files it was loading (I definitely did that a few days ago with some of them, but apparently not all of them).  ProcessFileData looks at a bit of the file, judges what kind of data it is, processes it accordingly and moves the appropriate distance along the file. Not recognising the out-of-date format in Chrome's cached file, it didn't process a bit and didn't move along, and got stuck, so like you say, it was an infinite loop.